# No connection in R

Tags: html, r, rvest

I've been trying to learn webscraping from an online course, and they give the following as an example

> url <- "https://www.canada.ca/en/employment-social-development/services/labour-relations/international/agreements.html"
> website<- read_html(url)
> treaties_links <- website %>% html_nodes("li") %>% html_nodes("a") %>% html_attr("href")
> treaties_links <-treaties_links[23:30]
> treaties_links_full <- lapply(treaties_links, function(x) (paste("https://www.canada.ca",x,sep="")))
> treaties_links_full[8] <-treaties_links[8]
> treaty_texts <- lapply(treaties_links_full, function(x) (read_html(x)))

When I get to this last line it returns an error

> Error in open.connection(x, "rb") :
> Could not resolve host: [www.canada.cahttp](http://www.canada.cahttp)

Comment: I'm not on a proxy btw

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error is in your `lapply()` code. If you print `treaties_links`, you will see that they are not all internal links, i.e. links starting with `/`, and some are links to other domains:

```r
print(treaties_links)
[1] "/en/employment-social-development/services/labour-relations/international/agreements/chile.html"
[2] "/en/employment-social-development/services/labour-relations/international/agreements/costa-rica.html"
[3] "/en/employment-social-development/services/labour-relations/international/agreements/peru.html"
[4] "/en/employment-social-development/services/labour-relations/international/agreements/colombia.html"
[5] "/en/employment-social-development/services/labour-relations/international/agreements/jordan.html"
[6] "/en/employment-social-development/services/labour-relations/international/agreements/panama.html"
[7] "http://www.international.gc.ca/trade-agreements-accords-commerciaux/agr-acc/honduras/labour-travail.aspx?lang=eng"
[8] "http://international.gc.ca/trade-commerce/assets/pdfs/agreements-accords/korea-coree/18_CKFTA_EN.pdf"
```

This means that when you are running `paste("https://www.canada.ca",x,sep="")` on e.g. link 7, you get:

```r
"https://www.canada.cahttp://www.international.gc.ca/trade-agreements-accords-commerciaux/agr-acc/honduras/labour-travail.aspx?lang=eng"
```

Assuming you want to keep that link you might change your `lapply` to:

```r
treaties_links_full <- lapply(
    treaties_links, 
    function(x) {
    ifelse(
        substr(x,1,1)=="/", 
        paste("https://www.canada.ca",x,sep=""),
        x
        )
    } 
)
```

This will only prepend `"https://www.canada.ca"` to the links within that domain.